# Как правильно удалять куку через Express?

Tags: express, cookie, сессия

Пробую использовать метод res.clearCookie, передавая в него те же параметры, которые были назначены куке при установке.

Если я правильно понял, сервер не может прямо указать клиенту, что куку следует удалить, поэтому указанный выше метод тупо перезаписывает файл таким образом, что Value обнуляется, а Expired оказывается моментом отправки ответа сервера клиенту (т.е. кука мгновенно устаревает).

Во-первых, хочется прояснить, действительно ли я правильно понимаю поведения Express?

Второй момент заключается в том, что Хром (при базовых настройках) куку не удаляет. Она продолжает висеть пустой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это нормальное поведение или я что-то не так делаю?

И если нормальное, то как все-таки удалить куку? Может быть, в middleware проверять наличие пустых кук и явно перезаписывать их с флагом session, чтобы браузер гарантированно удалил их после закрытия окна?

---

При обработке запроса я одновременно выставляю новую куку (sid) и снимаю старую. Код выгдядит так:

```js
                if (result?.setCookies?.length) {
                    for (const cookie of result.setCookies) {
                        res.cookie(cookie.name, cookie.value, cookie.options);
                        logger.trace(`Set cookie with name ${cookie.name}`);
                    }
                }


                if (result?.removeCookies?.length) {
                    for (const cookie of result.removeCookies) {
                        res.clearCookie(cookie.name, cookie.options);
                        console.log(cookie.name);
                        console.dir(cookie.options);
                        logger.trace(`Removed cookie with name ${cookie.name}`);
                    }
                }
```

Вот вывод консоль лога:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я правильно разобрался с документацией, то value в res.cleanCookie не передается, только name. Возможно, причина в параметре maxAge, который тоже нужно передавать пустым?

По итогу у меня получается две куки в браузере:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кука с пустым значением это нормально. Для очистки куки дату ставят на «начало эпохи», так что на картинке явно не результат вызова `res.clearCookie`.
А значит код в студию

Comment: @AlexeyTen я добавил в описание вопроса код и вывод лога. Спасибо, что откликнулись!

Answer (score 0):

Уберите из опций `maxAge`.

Метод `clearCookie` это просто «сахар» для `cookie` с установкой по умолчанию даты и пустого значения. Вы своим `maxAge` перетираете этот дефолт.

https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L802